# The right way to import React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the right way to import React `import React from 'react'` or `import react from 'react'` as VSCode is giving the second one as Auto-suggestion .

Answer (score 2):

Both work, it does not matter because you are getting the default export either way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the two examples you shared *other than* what you named the default export when you imported it. Either will work and are syntactically correct.

The standard convention is to Titlecase React when importing though:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of separate `jsx-runtime` (https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) it it is not necessary to explicitly import React.

Just use named imports:

```
import type { FunctionalComponent } from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```